# how to sum two values from database in yii

Tags: php, yii

I'm new to yii.I create one form that contain amount and totalamount. i have already store totalamount=1000 in database.if i give a value in amount it should add with totalamount and store it on database.i just try this but the value is not stored in database.

```
public function actiontransaction()
{
    $model = new Transactionform;
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) 
    {

        $model->username=$_POST['username'];
        $model->description=$_POST['description'];
        $model->amount=$_POST['amount'];    

        $model = Transactionform::model()->findByPK(27);
        echo $model-> totalamount+$model->amount=$_POST['amount'];
        $model->transactiondate=$_POST['transactiondate'];  

        if($model->validate())
        {
            if(!$model->save()) // save it here!
            {
                // do stuff after successful save
            }
        }

    }
    $this->render('bankreg',array('model'=>$model));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    ...
    $amount=$_POST['amount'];    //new amount
    $model = Transactionform::model()->findByPK(27);
    $model->totalamount = $model->totalamount + $amount; // total = previous + new
    ...
```

Comment: if i give findByPK($id) it gives an undefined id.but i defined all

Comment: I don't see `$id` in your action. Where is it?

Comment: Your question was about amount and totalamount. What's the problem in my code now?

Comment: your code adds previous amount and amount.but i want to add previous total amount and new amount.

Answer (score 0):

The value is not saved because you're not assigning it correctly to model.
It would be useful knowing what you have in $_POST (hope it contains the id of the object you're trying to modify, so you can use it in the call of findByPk to retrieve the data from database).
I try to edit your code:

```html
public function actionTransaction()
{
    $model = new Transactionform;
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) 
    {  
        $model = Transactionform::model()->findByPK($_POST['id']);
        $model->username = $_POST['username'];
        $model->description = $_POST['description'];
        $model->amount = $_POST['amount']; 
        $model->totalamount = $model->totalamount + $_POST['amount'];
        $model->transactiondate = $_POST['transactiondate']; 
   
        if($model->validate())
        {
            if(!$model->save()) // save it here!
            {
               // do stuff after successful save
            }
        }
    }
        $this->render('bankreg',array('model'=>$model));
}
```

Comment: can you update your question with the code of your view? 
you can try printing with var_dump your $_POST inside the action to see the data you're submitting with your form

Answer (score 0):

finally i got answer by using this method.

```html
 $model1=$model->findall();
          foreach($model1 as $model_amount)
       $total_amount=$model_amount['totalamount'];
    $amount=$_POST['amount'];   
  if($model->description=='D')  
         $model->totalamount = $total_amount + $amount;
```